# how to load libraries and creating object of another libraray class in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

link:http://henrypeteralbers.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html.

I have used this to solve my problem but fail to do say after struggling 4 hours in google  Please tell where I'm wrong. If run my file with including client file as library php throws an error :`Non-existent myclass file.`

1. how to create object of class my_class.

   2.how to  resolve error: Non-existent my_class error.

**controller file**

```
function a(){
     $this->load->library('my_class');
     $client = new OAuth2\my_class(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
              }
     and myclass.php in lib folder
     namespace oath2;
     class my_class
      {
      }

      here is core php code:
    require('common/Client.php');              // include php wrapper  class
    require('common/GrantType/IGrantType.php');// include php wrapper  class//
   require('common/GrantType/AuthorizationCode.php'); // include php wrapper  class//

      const CLIENT_ID     = '***********'; //generated from base_camp api//
      const CLIENT_SECRET ='***********'; 

      const REDIRECT_URI           = '***********';
       const AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = 'https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/new';
     const TOKEN_ENDPOINT         = 'https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/token';

         session_start();

    $client = new OAuth2\my_class(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
    if (!isset($_GET['code']))
     {
$_SESSION['org'] = $_GET['org'];
     $auth_url = $client->getAuthenticationUrl(AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT, REDIRECT_URI);
      header('Location: ' . $auth_url);
     die('Redirect');
        }
      else
     {
       $params = array( 'type' => 'web_server', 'client_id' => CLIENT_ID, 'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI, 'client_secret' => CLIENT_SECRET, 'code' => $_GET['code']);
$response = $client->getAccessToken(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, 'authorization_code', $params);

$client->setAccessToken($response['result']['access_token']);

$org = $_SESSION['org'].'_ess';
mysql_connect('localhost','root','*******') or die('Cannot connect to database !');
mysql_select_db($org) or die('No database found in mysql !');

$gcntct = mysql_query("select * from e_users");
if(mysql_num_rows($gcntct) != false)
{
    mysql_query("update ess_users set user_access_token = '".$response['result']['access_token']."', user_refresh_token = '".$response['result']['refresh_token']."'");
}

$auth = $client->fetch('https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization.json');
$counter = 0;
while($auth['result']['accounts'][$counter]['product'] != 'bcx')
{
    $counter++;
}
mysql_query("update e_user_info set Account_href = '".$auth['result']['accounts'][$counter]['href']."'");

header('Location: /'.$_SESSION['org'].'/wizard.php');
```

}

Comment: first change the filename to my_class.php

Comment: please check my updated code in object craetion with namespaces its ok but  with codeginator  namespaces example :oath2/classname in codignator it showing error:Non-existent class. where im wrong.

Comment: how to intailiaze  object in codgeinator

Comment: Where is your common folder located?

Comment: in libraries in codeginator

Answer (score 0):

```
 function a(){
     $this->load->library('my_class');
     $client = $this->my_class->function_name((CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
  }
 and my_class.php in lib folder
 class My_class
 {
    function function_name($a,$b)
    {
      //your code
    }
 }
```